# download cassansdra jbcd 1.2.3 jar

Tags: cassandra

Can someone give me a link to download the cassandra-jbcd.**1.2.3**.jar ?

The most recent version I found is cassandra-jbcd.1.2.1.jar and i really need the last version of cassandra for my work.

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's not in their downloads you can build it yourself using the [dependency](https://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/cassandra-jdbc/source/browse/pom.xml?name=trunk). Create a maven project add the dependency, compile the project and maven will create the jar for you.

```
<dependency>  
    <groupId>org.apache.cassandra</groupId>
    <artifactId>cassandra-clientutil</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.3</version>
</dependency>
```

[Here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/24593987/cassandra-jdbc-1.2.3.jar) is an example build, but I dont think it will be very long before it's out of date again.